# XSS protection from Vaadin UI

Tags: java, vaadin, xss

I have the backend with Vaadin UI. I want to protect the backend database from XSS attack.
What do you recommend for XSS protection from Vaadin UI?

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin has built in XSS protection. 
All components corretly escaping/encoding the html tags.

BUT: 
You have the possibility to show "raw" html or js code in some components.

For example the label has the possibility to send the html code unescaped back to your browser. If you do this, then you will be open to attacks.
In such cases you will have to make the correct filtering/escapes to prevent XSS attacks.

When a users enters this text in a text field:

```
<script>alert('test')</script>
```

Then that very same text, including all < > & ' etc. are saved in the backend/database.
No reason to do anything else after all.

When you then read back this from the database, the vaadin components (TextField, Label,...) correctly escape all the required html characters/tags/entities, so that the webbrowser displays this on the screen:

```
<script>alert('test')</script>
```

When you use some other kind of web ui, then of course it's the reponsibility of that ui layer to correctly escape all special characters.

More on the links below:

[The security page](https://vaadin.com/framework/security)

[More on vaadin security](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-security.html)

[Security Webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNAo3ApWA-A)

Comment: If wrote text with XSS attack in the TextField and saved this text to DB then we will have text with XSS attack in the database. Vaadin doesn`t protect from it.

Comment: @VolodymyrKusiak How is this a problem of Vaadin? Your question strongly suggests, that you want to protect Vaadin itself from XSS and not something else.  If you want to filter the user content, then this is Vaadin agnostic (although Vaadin already comes with Jsoup, which brings clearing of html to a whitelist)

Comment: @VolodymyrKusiak Vaadin handles all the escaping correctly. If a user enters <script>alert('Hacked')</script> in the text field, this very same text is stored in the database. (It's what the user has entered after all) When you then display this field from the database via vaadin, then vaadin again properly escapes all the required <, >, ' etc. characters, so that the text is displayed as text. If you use another way to display this db stored text in html, then that UI part has to do the correct escaping.